# Problem with Zend Framework Quickstart Tutorial and version 1.8.2

Tags: macos, zend-framework, zend-tool

I'm trying to work through the quick start tutorial of the Zend Framework version 1.8.2, but I'm getting an error when running this code:

```
zf.sh create project quickstart
error: expecting `'{'' in /Users/andrew/Sites/_library/ZendFramework-1.8.2/library/Zend/Tool/Framework/Client/Console.php on line 63
```

I'm doing this on Mac OS X 10.4. Is there an error in Zend Tool? or am I doing something wrong? Or is my environment not set up correctly to run this script?

I tried this on my other computer and got

```
-bash: zf.sh: command not found
```

I think this one is a separate problem, but not sure what to do

Comment: You should post this question to fw-general@lists.zend.com. From what I understand, Zend_Tool is still very young.

Answer (score 1):

to the second problem:

```
$ chmod +x zf.sh
```

or place it to /usr/bin (or where the other executables lives, don't know where it is in OS X)
or use

```
$ sh ./zf.sh
```

first problem:
which PHP version do you use? The problem exists maybe at multi interface implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you can still manually create the folder structure that Zend_Tool does, the quickstart guide does give examples of the naming conventions and there are numerous other examples. in order to better understand the framework, doing this manually can be good since your forced to think about the files your creating and how they are used.